# How to change line spacing in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, spacing, visual-studio-2019, productivity-power-tools

In Visual Studio 2017, I reduced line spacing to fit more code on the screen.

Today I downloaded Visual Studio 2019, however, I forgot how to change line spacing. I searched the options menu, installed Productivity Power Tools, Googled for answers, reviewed all my installed extensions but still cannot find how to reduce the space between lines.

Comment: best font for that using the same size 10, are Droid Sans Mono;
it reserves comment blocks slight cleaner without line gaps;

Answer (score 7):

There's a feature request to implement this in Visual Studio 2019. It seems to be in their backlog but no target release date nor status have been provided.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/896879/allow-users-to-set-line-height.html

In the meantime, maybe you could try to find a different Font to better achieve the desired results.

Or try this extension: [LinePress](https://github.com/omsharp/LinePress)

Comment: Yay!  Apr 2021, comment in linked thread mentions a release in an upcoming version of Visual Studio.

Comment: And the feature is now present in VS 2022 (Preview) under "Text Editor" ➝ "General" ➝ Group "Display" ➝ "Line spacing"

Answer (score 5):

## For VS 2015/2017/2019

Check out the [LinePress](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarRwemi.LinePress) extension available on the VS Marketplace. After installing it, just go to the Tools menu > Options > LinePress > Options and there you can change the line height of the text editor to your liking.
[image: LinePress settings]

## For VS 2022

There's a built-in setting for that, just open the Tools menu > Options > Text Editor > General and look for a setting called Line Spacing, change its value to one of your liking.
[image: Setting line height on VS 2022]

Comment: For VS2022 it is also possible to select more fine-grained line spacing, at least according to [this comment](https://github.com/omsharp/LinePress/issues/12#issuecomment-979262067).